# How do I fix this indexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been stuck for hours trying to figure out why my code has an index out of bounds exception, and how to fix it. The error occurs in the column calculations for `val` and `curVal`. In my code, it will throw the index 3, which is larger than my test Matrix, which has dimensions of 3x3.

```java
int outOfOrderCount = 0;
//finds outOfOrderCount
int val = 0;
int curVal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < curBoard.length*curBoard[0].length; i++) {
    val = curBoard[i % curBoard.length][i - (i % curBoard[0].length)];
    for(int cidx = i + 1; cidx < curBoard.length*curBoard[0].length; cidx++) {
        System.out.println(cidx % curBoard.length);
        System.out.println(cidx - (cidx-(cidx % curBoard[0].length)));
        curVal = curBoard[cidx % curBoard.length][cidx-(cidx % curBoard[0].length)];
        if(val < curVal) {
            outOfOrderCount++;
        }
     }
}
```

I have tried adding `-1` to both `[i  - (i % curBoard[0].length)]`, and `[cidx-(cidx % curBoard[0].length)]`, but both throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` at -1. What do I add to the equation so I can get an index of 2 max?

```java
int outOfOrderCount = 0;
//finds outOfOrderCount
int val = 0;
int curVal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < curBoard.length*curBoard[0].length; i++) {
    val = curBoard[i % curBoard.length][i - (i % curBoard[0].length)];
    for(int cidx = i + 1; cidx < curBoard.length*curBoard[0].length; cidx++) {
        System.out.println(cidx % curBoard.length);
        System.out.println(cidx - (cidx-(cidx % curBoard[0].length)));
        curVal = curBoard[cidx % curBoard.length][cidx-(cidx % curBoard[0].length)];
        if(val < curVal) {
            outOfOrderCount++;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop for variable `cidx` is checked to be less than `curBoard.length*curBoard[0].length` which is the size of all spots in the array `curBoard[][]` which if its a 3x3 as you say will max out at 9 which is greater than the number of rows in each column once it hits 4, hence the OutOfBoundsException